# woocommerce обработчик отправки в корзину

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, woocommerce

задача: отправить одним запросом в корзину несколько вариаций товара.
Как это вижу я: массив значений через POST в обработчик, далее перехватить перед размещением в корзину и разобрать массив, циклом добавить в корзину. Вопрос, где перехватить POST массив?

Или может какие то другие варианты есть?
P.S JS, JQ знаю плохо, варианты с Ajax видел, но не разобрался, может с ними поможет кто?

Answer (score 1):

решил через php
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($value, $_POST['quantity'][$key]);